# Ts ругается на RTK query и не предлагает автокомплит (phpStorm )

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, redux, phpstorm

Начал изучать redux toolkit и столкнулся с проблемой, что phpStorm не предлагает автокомплит для хуков из RTK query (`useSearchUsersQuery`, например).

А еще он мне выдает ошибку, которая протеворечит документации.
В документации так и написано `fetchBaseQuery({baseUrl: '/'})`, а у меня PhpStorm на такое написание ругается.

[image: Ошибка]

Вот мой tsconfig.json

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "DOM",
      "DOM.Iterable",
      "ESNext"
    ],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "rootDir": "./src",
    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    /* Linting */
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ],
      "@assets/*": [
        "./src/assets/*"
      ],
      "@pages/*": [
        "./src/pages/*"
      ],
      "@modules/*": [
        "./src/modules/*"
      ],
      "@components/*": [
        "./src/components/*"
      ],
      "@UI/*": [
        "./src/UI/*"
      ],
      "@hooks/*": [
        "./src/hooks/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Возможно, у меня tsconfig не так настроен? Но я пробовал разные конфиги - не получилось.
Как исправить ошибку и включить автокомплит?

Comment: Попробуйте перезагрузить IDE и если не поможет, то на крайняк можете использовать `as FetchBaseQueryArgs`

Comment: @EzioMercer пробовал, не помогло. Принудительная типизация ошибку убирает, но автокомплит всё равно не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня была старая версия PhpStorm (2021), обновился до последней версии, и всё заработало. Вероятно, версия 2021 года не поддерживала rtk query